# Jetpack Compose Exposed Dropdown Menu Assign Specific Variable

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to set a value for a specific var across my program based on input from an Exposed Dropdown Menu that I use across different Composables.

Declared my variables here:

```kotlin
val options = rememberSaveable {
    listOf("6% Sales Tax", "4% Res. Tax", "No Tax")
}

var taxVar by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
```

Here is my code for the Exposed Dropdown Menu:

```kotlin
@Composable
    fun ExposedDropdownMenuTax(
       taxVar: String, taxVarChanged: (newTaxVar: String) -> Unit,
       options: List<String>,
    ) {
        var expanded by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
            Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                .width(180.dp)
        ) {
            TextField(
                readOnly = true,
                value = taxVar,
                onValueChange = { taxVarChanged(it)},
                label = { Text("Tax") },
                trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
                colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
                modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
            )
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            ) {
                options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = selectionOption) },
                        onClick = {
 /* Tells me var cannot be changed */ taxVar = selectionOption
                            expanded = false
                        },
                        contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the only way I could get the box to populate on the different answers, but now my variable 'taxVar' is getting an error saying "var cannot be changed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin, [function parameters are immutable](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/kotlin-m5-1/#parameters-are-immutable). So you could consider a function parameter to implicitly be a `val`. 
Also, even if you were able to modify it, the parent Composable would not be aware of that change, and you would get inconsistencies.

Your code actually already contains the solution. You are passing a callback parameter called `taxVarChanged` into your `ExposedDropdownMenuTax` Composable. You should be calling that function to then update `taxVar` in the parent Composable:

```
DropdownMenuItem(
    text = { Text(text = selectionOption) },
    onClick = {
        taxVarChanged(selectionOption)
        expanded = false
    },
    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
)
```

Then in your parent Composable, you will be doing something like this:

```
@Composable
fun ParentComposable() {

    val options = rememberSaveable {
        listOf("6% Sales Tax", "4% Res. Tax", "No Tax")
    }
    
    var taxVar by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    // ...

    ExposedDropdownMenuTax(
        taxVar = taxVar,
        taxVarChanged = { newTaxVar ->
            taxVar = newTaxVar  // update value here
        },
        options = options
    )
}
```

Then, the value will be updated both in the parent and the child Composable.

Comment: I must have a different issue somewhere in my code then. The problem now exists where another composable is saying no value is passed to my variable 'taxVar'. From what I can see, it looks like I am sending that variable to it but something is missing. I will edit the post above to show it.

Comment: Decided to make it a new question since I believe my original problem was solved. Editing to remove the addition.